# Text File "printing" in VB.NET from VB6

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration, filewriter

I'm porting an application from VB6 to VB.NET and have come across something that VB.NET doesn't like. The "Print #" function (whatever its real name is). The code is as follows:

```
Open tmp For Output As TmpNo

    'save data from first form, frminput1
    Print #TmpNo, frmInput1.txtTitle
    Print #TmpNo, frmInput1.txtStrandWidth
    Print #TmpNo, frmInput1.txtStrandThick
    'MORE IS HERE, CUT DOWN BECAUSE IT'S TOO HEFTY

Close #TmpNo
```

I was just wondering what the equivalent of this in VB.NET is, as there is a LOT of this and I don't want to be here until the end of time.
Thanks!

Comment: It is called the 'Print #' Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Write` or `WriteLine` method for writing a file...

Some basic examples [Here](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/nets8p4.html) and [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamwriter-vbnet)

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)
objWriter.WriteLine(TextBox1.Text)
...
objWriter.Close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `StreamWriter` class instead:

```
Using writer = File.CreateText(path)
    writer.WriteLine(...)
End Using
```

Comment: Good idea, I was hoping there was a more simple way but this will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the functions provided by Microsoft instead of making stuff up.

**Print, PrintLine Functions**
Writes display-formatted data to a sequential file.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cksc646(v=VS.90).aspx

---

**Programming Element Support Changes Summary**

Support for various programming elements has changed since Visual Basic 6.0, mostly for interoperability with the common language runtime. Many Visual Basic 6.0 elements are renamed, reclassified, or combined with other programming elements. Several elements are no longer supported, because the common language runtime (CLR) includes functionality that makes them unnecessary. For more information, see Common Language Runtime.

For additional information about changes to Visual Basic, see Help for Visual Basic 6.0 Users. This topic includes information about changes to the integrated development environment (IDE), Web functionality, projects, forms, constants, and the Circle, Line, and Pset methods.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kaf4ssya(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: +1. Microsoft provided these functions to make it easy to port VB6 `Print #` to VB.Net